# What is the name of this squad-based battle game?

Tags: ios, game-identification

I found in the pictures of my old iPhone a screenshot of a game I used to play about 1-2 years ago.

[image: skeletons fire on the the main characters]

The goal was to compose a team of 4 members (picked among ~10 characters that all had unique abilities : rogue, knight, paladin, witch, mage etc.) and you had to progress by beating all the enemies on a level, sometime it was a Boss. You were rewarded with gold, items and XP.

I can't remember the name. I've tried searching the AppStore games with generic terms such as "knight" "beat them all" "battle" "magic" "rpg" etc. but had no luck so far. I also tried to google this image with no result. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: In the future, assuming your Apple account is still the same, I think you can just check your appstore history. Apple has a history of every game you ever downloaded, I believe, and you should be able to find this list somewhere in the appstore. I know the Google Play store has such a list.

Comment: @NateKerk That was the first placed I looked for it but I couldn't seem to find it. Maybe it's not compatible with iPad (since i searched for it on my iPad) but can't be sure. Also i've downloaded hudnerds of Apps since i created my account so I might have simply missed it :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Via a reverse image search of [this piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKspb.png), I found the game.

It's called Battleheart ([Google Play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.KelliNoda.Battleheart) | [IOS Appstore link](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/battleheart/id394057299?mt=8)).

[image]

Comment: How did you do that ? reverse image search gave me nothing ! Anyway thanks a lot :D

Comment: I didn't use the whole image. Cropped some sprites and I found it.

Comment: Nice,it didn't occur to me. Gotta go, I have some unproductive hours of game ahead of me =D